# how i can add a List of sessions in the List of patient Sqflite in the Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

//detials of patient

I want to add a set of sessions for each patient. I am using two tables in the Sqflite database, the first for the patient and the second for the sessions. Is it possible to add a list of sessions?

---

```
// ignore_for_file: use_key_in_widget_constructors, unnecessary_this, must_be_immutable, prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables, no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers, unnecessary_brace_in_string_interps, use_build_context_synchronously, unrelated_type_equality_checks, iterable_contains_unrelated_type

import 'package:clinic/Models/session.dart';
import 'package:clinic/services/session_database_helper.dart';
import '../Screens/add_patient.dart';
import '../widgets/session_widget.dart';
import '../Models/patient_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PatientPersonalData extends StatelessWidget {
  final PatientData patient;

  PatientPersonalData({required this.patient, this.session});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(300, deviceSize.height * 0.40),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/'),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
                ),
                const Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                  "Patient Data",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => AddPatient(
                          patient: patient,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    "Edit",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.teal),
              child: Text("ID:   ${patient.id}"),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 50,
                    child: Text(
                      patient.patientName,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 50,
                    child: Text(
                      patient.patientId,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 5, vertical: 3),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.teal,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 30,
                        child: Text(
                          patient.patientSex,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blueGrey,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 30,
                        child: Text(
                          patient.patientAge,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<SessionData>?>(
          future: SessionDatabaseHelper.getSessionByPatientId(
              patientId: patient.id!),
          builder:
              (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<SessionData>?> snapshotSession) {
            if (snapshotSession.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else if (snapshotSession.hasError) {
              return Text(snapshotSession.error.toString());
            } else if (snapshotSession.hasData) {
              if (snapshotSession.data != null) {
                final listSnapshotSession = snapshotSession.data
                    ?.where((element) => element.patientId == patient.id)
                    .toList();
                return ListView.separated(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => SessionWidget(
                        patientId: patient.id ?? 0,
                        session: listSnapshotSession.elementAt(index),
                        onTap: () {},
                        onLongPress: () async {
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (ctx) {
                                return AlertDialog(
                                  title: const Text(
                                    "Are you sure need to Delete Session ?",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 25,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                                  actions: [
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                      style: ButtonStyle(
                                        backgroundColor:
                                            MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                                Colors.red.shade900),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        await SessionDatabaseHelper
                                            .deleteSession(
                                                snapshotSession.data![index]);
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                      child: const Text("Delete"),
                                    ),
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                        child: const Text("No"))
                                  ],
                                );
                              });
                        }),
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SessionWidget(
                        patientId: patient.id ?? 0,
                        session: listSnapshotSession.elementAt(patient.id!),
                        onTap: () {},
                        onLongPress: () async {
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (ctx) {
                                return AlertDialog(
                                  title: const Text(
                                    "Are you sure need to Delete Session ?",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 25,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                                  actions: [
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                      style: ButtonStyle(
                                        backgroundColor:
                                            MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                                Colors.red.shade900),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        await SessionDatabaseHelper
                                            .deleteSession(
                                                snapshotSession.data![index]);
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                      child: const Text("Delete"),
                                    ),
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                        child: const Text("No"))
                                  ],
                                );
                              });
                        }),
                    itemCount: listSnapshotSession!.length);
              }
            }
            return const Center(child: Text("No session Added yet!"));
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          buildShowModalBottomSheet(context, patient.id!);
        },
        child: const Text(
          "Session",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  final SessionData? session;
  int numSession = 1;

  int countNumSession() {
    return numSession++;
  }

  void buildShowModalBottomSheet(BuildContext ctx, int patientId) {
    final _prescriptionController = TextEditingController();
    final _paymentController = TextEditingController();
    final _noteController = TextEditingController();
    final _patientIdController = TextEditingController();

    void addOrUpdateSession() async {
      final prescription = _prescriptionController.value.text;
      final note = _noteController.value.text;
      final payment = _paymentController.value.text;
      final time = DateTime.now();
      final sessionNumber = numSession;
      final patientIdInSession = _patientIdController.value.text;
      if (prescription.isEmpty ||
          note.isEmpty ||
          payment.isEmpty ||
          time.toIso8601String().isEmpty) {

        // patientIdInSession.isEmpty || patientIdInSession != patient.id
        print("patientIdInSession $patientIdInSession");
        return;
      } else {
        final SessionData sessionModel = SessionData(
          sessionNum: sessionNumber,
          id: session?.id,
          prescription: prescription,
          note: note,
          payment: payment,
          time: time,
          patientId: int.tryParse(patient.id.toString()) ?? 0,
        );
        if (session == null) {
          await SessionDatabaseHelper.addSession(sessionModel,
              patientId: patientId);
          print("session added $sessionModel");
        } else {
          await SessionDatabaseHelper.updateSession(sessionModel, patientId);
          print("session updated $sessionModel");
        }
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(ctx).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text("Session Added!"),
          ),
        );
        Navigator.pop(ctx);
        countNumSession();
      }
    }

    showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25)),
        ),
        elevation: 2,
        context: ctx,
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
          if (session != null) {
            _prescriptionController.text = session!.prescription;
            _noteController.text = session!.note;
            _paymentController.text = session!.payment;
            numSession = session!.sessionNum;
          }
          return Wrap(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 20),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.tealAccent,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                              ),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              width: 35,
                              height: 35,
                              child: Text(
                                  "# ${session?.sessionNum ?? numSession}",
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20)),
                            ),
                            const Text(
                              "Session",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Text(
                            "${session == null ? DateTime.now() : session!.time}"),
                        const SizedBox(height: 15),
                        Form(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                controller: _prescriptionController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.teal.shade800,
                                          width: 1.2)),
                                  label: const Text("prescription"),
                                  hintText: "Enter Diagnosis",
                                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.pregnant_woman_outlined,
                                    color: Colors.teal,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5),
                              TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                controller: _noteController,
                                minLines: 2,
                                maxLines: 5,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.teal.shade800,
                                          width: 1.2)),
                                  label: const Text("Note"),
                                  hintText: "Note",
                                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.text_snippet,
                                    color: Colors.teal,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5),
                              TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                controller: _paymentController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.teal.shade800,
                                          width: 1.2)),
                                  label: const Text("Payment"),
                                  hintText: "Remaining amount..",
                                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.add_card,
                                    color: Colors.teal,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 15),
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                addOrUpdateSession();
                              },
                              child: Text(session == null ? "Save" : "Update"),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width: 20),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () async => Navigator.pop(ctx),
                                child: const Text("Cancel")),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

//database patient model

```
class PatientData {


  final int? id;
  final String patientName;
  final String patientId;
  final String patientSex;
  final String patientAge;
  final String diagnosis;


  const PatientData({  this.id,
    required this.patientName,
    required this.patientId,
    required this.patientAge,
    required this.patientSex,
    required this.diagnosis,});

  factory PatientData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PatientData(
        id: json["id"],
        patientName: json["patientName"],
        patientId: json["patientId"],
        patientAge: json["patientAge"],
        patientSex: json["patientSex"],
        diagnosis: json["diagnosis"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'id': id,
    'patientName': patientName,
    'patientId': patientId,
    'patientAge': patientAge,
    'patientSex': patientSex,
    'diagnosis': diagnosis,

  };

}
```

//database Helper of patient

```
// ignore_for_file: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers, depend_on_referenced_packages


import '../Models/patient_data.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static const int _version = 1;
  static const String _dbName = "Patient.db";

  static Future<Database> _getDB() async {
    return openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), _dbName),
      onCreate: (db, _version) => db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE PatientData (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
              "patientName TEXT NOT NULL, "
              "patientId TEXT NOT NULL, "
              "patientAge TEXT NOT NULL, "
              "patientSex TEXT NOT NULL, "
              "diagnosis TEXT NOT NULL);"),
      version: _version,
    );
  }

  static Future<int> addPatient(PatientData patient) async {
    final db = await _getDB();
    return await db.insert(
      "PatientData",
      patient.toJson(),
      nullColumnHack: "Null",
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  static Future<int> updatePatient(PatientData patient) async {
    final db = await _getDB();
    return db.update(
      "PatientData",
      patient.toJson(),
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [patient.id],
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  static Future<List<PatientData>?> readPatientByName(
      final String patientName) async {
    final db = await _getDB();
    db.query(
      _dbName,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [patientName],
    );
    return null;
  }

  static Future<int> deletePatient(PatientData patient) async {
    final db = await _getDB();
    return db.delete(
      "PatientData",
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [patient.id],
    );
  }

  static Future<List<PatientData>?> readAllPatient() async {
    final db = await _getDB();

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query("PatientData");
    if (maps.isEmpty) {
      return null;
    }
    return List.generate(
        maps.length, (index) => PatientData.fromJson(maps[index]));
  }
}
```

if you need to Have a look at the project you have a gir

[link_github](https://github.com/Nasim55/clinic)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.